# Two way communication between .NET and Python

Tags: .net, python.net

My main application is a .NET desktop application which relies on some calls to python script for AI. I'd like to know if there are some guidelines/recommandations toward how to best have my python code able to use functions from my .net app. Shall I pass functions or shall I have python code also using python.net to callback some functions?

One example of such pattern would be logging. I am using `Serilog` and I would like to reuse my .NET configuration for Python. Another example would be a function to read some proprietary content where the code exists in .net not in python.

I am currently using Python.NET successfully to call Python functions from my .NET application.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a magic bullet for you. Essentially, you are right: if one wants to share logging and other infrastructure they would need to write [adapters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for one or another language depending on preference.

It would probably be a good idea (for the community) to share those adapters as an open source projects.

Comment: Thanks! I know there is no silver bullet, that's why I am asking for recommandations. I would like to avoid exploring tons of options that people would have already explored. Before going for a big communication layer between the 2 stacks, I'd like to start with simple "tricks". For example, I don't manage to simply pass a .net method to python.